# Как правильно создать несколько потоков с асинхронными методами?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Мне нужно сделать 2 потока в которых запустить асинхронно методы, как это лучше всего сделать? На данный момент я могу придумать только одно решение:

```
new Thread(async () => await MyAsyncMethod1()).Start();
new Thread(async () => await MyAsyncMethod2()).Start();
```

Но смогу ли я отлавливать исключения в таких методах, ведь `async ()` - это `void` метод, а следовательно я не смогу поймать исключение, если оно там будет. Или я ошибаюсь в суждении?

Comment: `async ()` - это сигнатура передачи *параметров* функции, она ничего не говорит о возвращаемом результате

Comment: Почему именно потоки, а не Task? С Task'ами ведь и можно ловить исключения. И работатс ними довольно удобная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете так просто запустить асинхронный метод в потоке, первый же оператор await остановит поток. Потоки - они для синхронных задач, для асинхронных используйте `Task.Run`

Если вам совсем-совсем нужен выделенный поток - гуглите как писать однопоточный планировщик задач.

Comment: Мне вообще надо запустить в сумме 4 async метода (по двое) и чтобы эти пары работали параллельно. Я хотел запустить 2 потока, а в них по 2 async метода, но видимо в этом нет смысла. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Aarnihauta `Task.Run`